# emms : how to change track format in playlist?

Tags: emms

I want to change the format of tracks displayed in my emms playlist.

Right now it shows (I think) artist name and info title, like this :

> Chuck Berry - Almost grown

I would like to have at least : Artist - album - track number - title.

I tried this config with no luck :

```lisp
    (use-package emms-setup
      :ensure nil
      :init
      (add-hook 'emms-player-started-hook 'emms-show)
      ;; sadly this does not what I want ##################
      (defvar emms-browser-info-title-format "%i%a%A%n%cS")
      (defvar emms-browser-playlist-info-title-format
        emms-browser-info-title-format)
      ;; end ##############################################
      :config
      (setq emms-show-format "Playing: %s")
      (emms-all)
      (emms-default-players)
      (setq emms-source-file-default-directory "~/Musique/")
      )
```

Which variable should I change ?

Answer (score 0):

`emms-show-format` shows whatever the function pointed to by `emms-track-description-function` returns for the given track.  The function takes a single argument (the track) and you can roll your own.

See the implementation of `emms-info-track-description`in `emms-info.el` for ideas on how to get started.